# React limit api results and view more items

Tags: reactjs

I am doing conditional rendering on my page and limiting the number of items a user can view in a component to 5. However, i want a user to have the option of viewing all items when they click more.

I have tried adding the view more button to show all results in the same component but only the button appears and there no items. When i console.log, the items are there. What have i missed to make the items and button appear.

My code

```
,<Item.Group divided>
                
              {
                commentData !== ""?(
                
                  commentData.slice(0,5).map((data, index) => {

                    var x = new Date(data.comment_date)

                    data.comment_date = x.toDateString();

                    console.log('review---', data)
                    return (

                      <Item key={index}>
                      <Item.Content>
                      
                        <Item.Description>By: {data.user_name} On : {data.comment_date}  </Item.Description> 
                        
                        <Rating maxRating={5} defaultRating={data.rate} icon='star' size='large' />
                        
                        <Item.Description>{data.comment}</Item.Description>
                        
                      </Item.Content>
                      </Item>
                    );  

                  }),  

                  <Button color='red' onClick={() => { 

                    commentData.map((data, index) => {
  
                    var x = new Date(data.comment_date)
  
                    data.comment_date = x.toDateString();
  
                    console.log('review---', data)
                    return (
  
                    <Item key={index}>
                    <Item.Content>
  
                      <Item.Description>By: {data.user_name} On : {data.comment_date}  </Item.Description> 
                      
                      <Rating maxRating={5} defaultRating={data.rate} icon='star' size='large' />
                      
                      <Item.Description>{data.comment}</Item.Description>
                      
                    </Item.Content>
                    </Item>
                    );  
  
                    })                    
  
                }} > View More </Button> 

                ):
                
                <Header as='h2'>
                Be the first one to review
                </Header>
              }

              <Divider/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You took an incorrect approach here by duplicating your code.
You should use thee state and store there the limit that you want to display (5 in your case). When the button is clicked, this value should be removed (set to null for example) and then you should render everything based on the state. This is the way I see it (consider it pseudo code):

```
const [limit, setLimit] = useState(5);

return (
<>
   items.slice(0, limit ? limit : items.length).map(item => /* render item logic */)
   <button onClick={() => setLimit(null)}>Save</button>
</>
```